# Are there any significant benefits in increasing my exercise frequency from 3 times a week to 5 times a week?

Tags: exercise

I have a sedentary job.

Currently I'm exercising 3 times a week, in the gym: 30~ 35 minutes of intensive cardiovascular exercise, and 25~30 minutes of strength training.

Are there any significant benefits in increasing my exercise frequency from 3 times a week to 5 times a week, while maintaining the same exercise regime?

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad to answer. Yes there will be benefits, you'll become better at what you do, you'll progress at a faster rate. Is this significant? Well that depends on what you think is significant... Are you training for anything specific? Do you have any goals? I don't think you can get a satisfying answer to this question right now.

Answer (score 1):

im not sure what your strength training consists of or what the intensive cardio training is of. but my gym regime is 4 days a week sometimes a 5th with each day a different muscle group so that there is adequate rest for the tired areas. my cardio is a walk for 20 mins each morning on a treadmill with a around an 8 percent incline. depending on what you want to get out of your exercise. im looking at holding and increasing muscle mass while becoming lean. if you train cardio to hard you will burn muscle. 20- 35 minutes of strength training over 3 times a week is not enough to properly train all your muscle groups. again it depends on what your looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are always benefits to doing a little more exercise if you can. So yes, if you can train 5x a week, I'd say go for it.

That being said, I wouldn't do 5x a week of ~30-35 min. of cardio mixed with ~25-30 minutes of resistance training.

It's just generally not that advisable to do resistance training on back-to-back days (assuming you're doing full body training). So I'd consider structuring things differently if you want to train 5x a week.

For instance:

- 3x a week on non-consecutive days do ~40-45 minutes of full-body resistance training, followed by 15-20 minutes of cardio. On the days in between do ~≤60 minutes of pure cardio and/or more mobility work
- 4x a week of an upper/lower split ([or an X Split](https://www.skillbasedfitness.com/x-split-routine/)), so maybe Mon/Tues/Thur/Fri of ~30-40 minutes of resistance training, followed by ~20-30 of cardio, and do ~≤60 minutes of cardio and/or maybe more mobility work on your other day

Something like that. This just allows for adequate recovery and makes sure you're getting enough rest between resistance training bouts. Aerobic training you can do near daily, but resistance training typically needs a day off between the same muscle groups and [High Intensity Cardio 5x a week will be way too much](https://www.skillbasedfitness.com/what-hiit-is-and-what-hiit-isnt/).

Otherwise you have to use crazy weird split resistance training routines, which are probably overkill at this point. Best to keep things as simple as possible.

It's just not the frequency of training that matters, you also have to consider volume and intensity among rest/recovery.

Comment: I did similar 3x/week workouts, 20-30min strength training, 30-40min cardio. Thought I was "exercising" & "staying healthy". I switched to 7 day "Push/Pull/Legs" split & results are awesome.

Now I do 45-60min of push exercises using variety of upper body muscle groups on day 1, then same of pull exercises on day 2, & same of leg exercises on day 3. Repeat on days 4-6. Active rest on day 7 with cardio and abs.

I'm working out 7x/week & each muscle group has 48 hours to rest between workouts, which actually allows my muscles to grow.

'Progressive overload' & eating a LOT are important.

Comment: Awesome glad you found something that works for you. I suppose my only gripe about that type of split is that the upper body gets twice the volume. Sometimes it needs it, but most importantly, it has to work for you.